Sftp paramiko and sshd-mina not able to write on remote server even if no error. On local sftp server it works though
I'm just showing the code used to try to upload a file in sftp:
# Check file size
def check_file_size(path):
    try:
        size = os.path.getsize(path)
        print(f"Local file size: {size} bytes")
        return size
    except OSError as e:
        print(f"Failed to get size of {path}: {e}")
        return None

# Create an SFTP session
def create_sftp_session(hostname, port, username, password):
    transport = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
    transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
    return sftp, transport

# Upload a file to the remote server, overwriting if it exists
def upload_file(sftp, local_path, remote_path, retries=3):
        try:
            # Create a temporary file and copy content to it
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
                with open(local_path, 'r') as file:
                    temp_file.write(file.read().encode())
                temp_file_path = temp_file.name
            
            local_size = os.path.getsize(temp_file_path)
            sftp.put(temp_file_path, remote_path)
            remote_size = sftp.stat(remote_path).st_size
            print(f"Remote file size after upload: {remote_size} bytes")
            if local_size != remote_size:
                print(f"Warning: Size mismatch after upload!")
            
            # Clean up temporary file
            os.remove(temp_file_path)
        except IOError as e:
            print(f"Failed to upload {local_path} to {remote_path}: {e}")

# Delete the local file
def delete_local_file(path):
    try:
        os.remove(path)
        print(f"Local file {path} deleted.")
    except OSError as e:
        print(f"Failed to delete {path}: {e}")

# Main execution
def main():
    # Create the local file
    create_local_file(local_file_path)

    # Set up SFTP session and upload file
    sftp, transport = create_sftp_session(hostname, port, username, password)
    try:
        # Upload and overwrite the file
        upload_file(sftp, local_file_path, remote_file_path)
    finally:
        sftp.close()
        transport.close()

    # Delete the local file
    delete_local_file(local_file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

If run against a remote server it fails:
Failed to upload localfile.txt to /dir/removefile.csv: size mismatch in put!  94 != 141
I run the same code against a local sftp server with docker and it works. Same for the code using sshd-mina (not shown here). This is the unexpected. Why it doesn't work against the remote server?
Another thing that I noticed is that, if I change the upload_file function as:
# Upload a file to the remote server, overwriting if it exists
def upload_file(sftp, local_path, remote_path, retries=3):
    for attempt in range(retries):
        try:
            # Create a temporary file and copy content to it
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
                with open(local_path, 'r') as file:
                    temp_file.write(file.read().encode())
                temp_file_path = temp_file.name
            
            local_size = os.path.getsize(temp_file_path)
            sftp.put(temp_file_path, remote_path)
            remote_size = sftp.stat(remote_path).st_size
            print(f"Remote file size after upload: {remote_size} bytes")
            if local_size != remote_size:
                print(f"Warning: Size mismatch after upload!")
            
            # Clean up temporary file
            os.remove(temp_file_path)
            break  # Exit loop if upload is successful
        except IOError as e:
            print(f"Attempt {attempt + 1} failed to upload {local_path} to {remote_path}: {e}")
            if attempt < retries - 1:
                print("Retrying...")
                time.sleep(5)  # Wait before retrying

It works at the second attempt! (the change consists in just retrying if an exception is raised).

Local file localfile.txt created with content. Attempt 1 failed to
upload localfile.txt to /flex-selections/Portfolio.csv: size mismatch
in put!  94 != 141 Retrying... Remote file size after upload: 141
bytes Local file localfile.txt deleted.

How is this possible?

After upload Paramiko checks, if the uploaded file has an expected size. The server reports smaller size than what Paramiko uploaded. It's not a client-side problem. It's server-side problem. Either the server stored the file incorrectly, or it incorrectly reads/reports the file size. No change in client code can fix this. If the file is saved incorrectly, you need to fix the server. If the server just fails to report the size correctly, you can workaround it by skipping the size check in Paramiko side with confirm=False parameter.

This is what I thought. It’s server side problems but this doesn’t answer to the questions: why I can upload a file with FileZilla. Why the above modified code work at exactly the second attempt.

Cannot you upload the file with Paramiko as well? Did you check, if it was uploaded correctly, despite the error message? It possibly was. That's my second variant: "If the server just fails to report the size correctly, you can workaround it by skipping the size check in Paramiko side with confirm=False parameter."

This has nothing to do with Spring or even Java at all. Please, be sure that you chose correct tags for your questions.

No, the file is not updated at all. So the paramiko error is excepted. I've contacted the server owner as I don't know what else to do.

Post [mcve], with logs. And a matching FileZilla log.

Well I cannot post a reproducible example, without knowing the server configuration. However they confirmed their server is buggy and non processing the sftp commands correctly as it is supposed to. I’ll update with answer after I finished to test a workaround

The problem was on server side. The legacy S/FTP frontdoor used does not fully support all SFTP commands/features (It's a FTP server with a SFTP enhancement.).
The S/FTP frontdoor does not properly process the target directory from the "put" method and does not forward a "CWD" command to the FTP server.
Workaround: Adding "chdir()" or "listdir()" before the "put()" forces a "CWD" and solved the problem. This is what I think Filezilla does.

Indeed, it's perfectly possible that it's SFTP server bug and a different sequence of commands can workaround the problem. But note that there's no "CWD"/"chdir" in SFTP protocol. SFTP always works with absolute paths. So your specific explanation won't hold.

The server is in fact not a real SFTP server. Run sftp.chdir(path) where path = remote_path.split(“/“) before .put makes the latest to work

Doesn't matter. It's still SFTP server.

Well that’s the explanation they gave me. I’m not an expert of this protocol to be honest, especially of this particular setup. Must be CD instead of CWD then

There's no "change working directory" functionality in SFTP protocol, no matter what you call it (cd/cwd/chdir).

Your last statement is not very clear. Cd is a supported command https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/sftp-commands-cheat-sheet/ and sftp clients allow to change working dir. where your statement comes from?

I'm writing about the protocol, not the client. The point is that although that client might simulate the working directory locally, the server never learns about it, as the SFTP protocol only ever works with absolute paths and is state-less (contrary to how FTP protocol works).
